# windows 10 reinstalled / wrong default name used

Tags: windows-10

My PC crashed and would not reboot. This affected my hard drive which lost most of my data. I had the hard drive replaced with a SSD and had Win10 reinstalled from scratch.  The tech that did the work for me used the name "owner" when he installed Win 10 (as in: c:\users\owner...) but all of my backups used my name leeh (as in: c:\users\leeh...).  I restored all of my backups and everything is working fine  - execept that my default is now "user" and I have the two user files "owner" and "leeh".    I do not want to create any issues with trying to change the default or lose any restored data that I might need, so is it possible to copy the "leeh" into "user" (skipping duplicates) then delete the "leeh" user file?  I created a new profile "leeh" and changed that to be my default account thinking that woudl solve the issue, but any software install still uses the "user" account.  I'm just really confused to how all of this works, so any tips would be appreciated.  BTW...I am the only person that uses this PC.

Comment: Make a folder C;\temp (neutral from Users) and copy documents and files from owner and leeh to c:\temp.

Now make a new user to suit yourself and make sure it is a member of administrators.  

Restart as the new user you set up, check that c:\temp has the documents you want and then in Advanced System Settings, Profiles, delete the two Windows Profiles.

Comment: thanks! The advance system settings/profile is the missing link that I did not know about.

Comment: If I post an answer as above would you wish to acknowledge it?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do here is to make a folder C:\temp (neutral from Users) and copy documents and files from owner and leeh to c:\temp.

Now make a new user to suit yourself and make sure it is a member of administrators. Restart as the new user you set up, check that c:\temp has the documents you want and then in Advanced System Settings, Profiles, delete the two Windows Profiles.